# Suitescript Modify Current Record

Tags: netsuite

I've looked all over but can't seem to find how to modify an existing record using Suitescript. Essentially I want to be able to set a field on the record that initiates the script. For example, when I view a custom record, Potential Resource, and save it - it initiates the script (which does happen); but how do I get the information from the record that initiated the script?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

-- This is what I have in my .js

```
function getMaxEmployeeNumber(){
var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType()), nlapiGetRecordId());
record.setFieldValue('Last Name', 'Set from script');
}
```

I don't know if this helps but in NetSuite I've done the following:
1. Created a new User Event script called "Employee Number Creation"
2. Created a script file that has one function in it (above) and added it to my script under the "Scripts" tab.
3. Created a deployment that applies to a custom record (Potential Resource)with a status of "Testing" and an event type of "Edit".

Comment: Lawd have mercy...I think I got it. 

After reading over the nlobjRecord API documentation I noticed the line "An nlobjRecord object of an existing NetSuite record. This function returns the record object exactly as the record appears in the system. Therefore, in beforeLoad user event scripts, if you attempt to change a field and load the record simultaneously, the change will not take effect."

I set the "After Submit Function" to my function above and it worked! Though I don't understand why it wouldn't when I have the function in the "Before Submit Function".

Comment: In other cases where you use nlapiLoadRecord() you will need to be sure to use the nlapiSubmitRecord() function to commit the changes you've made.

Not your particular situation but worth noting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to hook a script up to "saving" a record. You can use a client script to attach to the "Save Record" event, which allows you to validate the record and prevent it from saving if necessary.

You can also use a User Event script and attach to either the "Before Submit" event, where you can modify any fields before the record gets to the database, or to the "After Submit" event, where you can take actions on other records after the record is committed to the database.

In either script, you can use the `nlapiGetFieldValue` and related functions to retrieve information from fields on the record, and `nlapiSetFieldValue` and related functions will update fields on the record.

Edit: Search the NetSuite Help for "Record API" to see the documentation for all record-related functions you can use.

Comment: How come you have to do an API call to get the fields' values? Is there a way to get the current record object and update its fields directly in a beforeSubmit event/hook script?

Comment: Those API calls are in fact operating on the current record; in SuiteScript 1.0, the NetSuite engine places the current record object in the global context, and these API calls operate on it that way. There are other ways to interact with the current record, but this is the simplest. If you investigate that "Record API" page, you will see other methods of retrieving a reference to the current record, such as `nlapiGetNewRecord`.

Comment: so you could say that nlapiGetFieldValue(field_id) and nlapiGetNewRecord().getFieldValue(field_id) would be equivalent? or is one a preferred way over the other?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying :) I did have a look at their documentation but I find it is not terribly helpful.. to many circular definitions.

Comment: You need to be careful when doing `nlapiGetNewRecord`, depending on what event type you are processing. When the event type is `xedit` (an inline edit by a user or by `nlapiSubmitField`), the instance returned by `nlapiGetNewRecord` only contains fields that have changed, not all fields on the record.

Comment: okay, so when using API calls like nlapiGetFieldValue(), is there a way to choose whether it gathers the data from the global current record and the record which is already saved in the database?

Comment: The record is not committed to the database until the `After Submit` event.  I've got a playlist on YT that explains the fundamentals of how User Events work and how the database fits in: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG2tK6Va2WUCseA3viGC2oYPkyA45wfA-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131739/discussion-between-pitt-and-erictgrubaugh).

Answer (score 0):

BeforeLoad works well for doing things like adding custom buttons to the form. Surely, you don't want to change the actual record before it gets displayed to the user.

Your setFieldValue function call needs to reference the ID of the custom field on the custom record. The fields are called something like "custrecord_whatever_you_named_it". Best practice is to enter "_whatever" in the ID field when creating the custom field. For example, "_last_name". If you had a field with this ID, your script would look like this:

```
record.setFieldValue('custrecord_last_name', 'Set from script');
```

Also, if you are using a User Event script that initializes a value (like setting an ID), you don't need to load the record. Just use this in a BeforeLoad function:

```
nlapiSetFieldValue('XXXXX', 'YYYYY');
```

Comment: There are plenty of times you might want to set fields before they are displayed to the users, which can be done in Before Load. Non-stored, calculated fields, for instance.

Comment: A non-stored calculated field can be defined as a custom field. No need to script it.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to set a field.

For client side you can use durectly nlapiSetFieldValue.

Or server, you can load the record by either rec=nlapiGetNewRecord or rec=nlapiLoadRecord, and then set the field with rec.setFieldValue, nlapiSubmit(rec).

Something I've found works best in most cases is nlapiSubmitField, to do a direct edit. Is the operation that tends to fail the least.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the record once you have modified it. You can submit the record using the function **nlapiSubmitRecord()**

Here's the sample code.

```
function getMaxEmployeeNumber()
{
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType()), nlapiGetRecordId());
    record.setFieldValue('Last Name', 'Set from script');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed submitting the record that's why the values you set did not reflect.

See nlapiSubmitRecord() API

Answer (score 0):

var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType()), nlapiGetRecordId());

This line has an extra parenthesis and won't even execute without throwing an error.  Correct it to this as well as submitting the record when you are done.

var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());